# Loopback: Create new DTO fields out of models

Tags: node.js, rest, loopbackjs

I have a loopback2 API service. I am able to not expose certain fields through the RESTful layer by making them `hidden` in the model JSON definition file.

I would like to able to create also new fields to expose in my DTO based on other properties without exposing these.

For example, say my model has fields `firstname` and `surname` and I want to expose a new `fullname` (firstname + surname) through the REST API but no the other two.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this was a bit of a silly question. Loopback doesn't give you any declarative way of providing new properties for your DTO as it does when you want to hide some but you have available all the flexibility you want through remote hooks.

For instance:

```
Person.afterRemote('*.find', function (ctx, user, next) {
  if(ctx.result) {
      ctx.result.forEach(function (result) {
        result.fullname = `${result.firstname} ${result.surname}`;
        delete result.firstname;
        delete result.surname;
      });
  }

  next();
});
```

You can narrow down your remote hook expression as much as you need to only provide this behaviour for the endpoints you care about.